# Conditional Tags to display CSS

Tags: php, css, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying to use a Conditional Tags to enable or disable a CSS class according to the page being shown. The problem is that the code is not running. Something is probably wrong with the syntax or logic. I thought about using a conditional statement using the template "agent_list.php," so that the CSS only runs when the user is in this template. Sorry about any confusions, it is really difficult to explain.

This is a draft of my code:

```
<?php    
      if (is_agent_list()) {
          <div class="geolocation-button <?php print $hidden_class; ?>" id="geolocation-button"> </div> 
          <div id="tooltip-geolocation"> <?php _e('place me on the map','wpestate');?> </div>   
          }
?>
```

Please let me know how if you have any suggestion. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: sorry but what is the problem / question here? U need your solution with working php syntax?

Comment: I am trying to run an if statement with CSS. I think I have problems with the syntax. The goal is to show or not show the CSS based on the template "agent_list.php" This is why I am using if (is_agent_list()).

Comment: @slaver113 Sorry that my question is not very clear. I am trying to do my best. The problem is that the code is not running. Something is wrong with the syntax or logic. The goal is to show or not show the CSS between the two brackets. For this I using a conditional statement based on the template "agent_list.php" If this template is shown, then I want to display the CSS. Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I can help you, I'm just not sure if I understand question.

Propoer syntax for your code will be:

```
<?php    
      if (is_agent_list()) { //close phptag here and begin html ?>  
          <div class="geolocation-button <?php print $hidden_class; ?>" id="geolocation-button"> </div> 
          <div id="tooltip-geolocation"> <?php _e('place me on the map','wpestate');?> </div>   
 <?php   }   //open php again to close if block with "}"  ?>
```

WIth code like this both divs will show up only when `is_agent_list()` returns true

Comment: I am trying this but the code is still not running. Maybe I am missing something else. I know the div class and id are working because if I take out the if statement they run.

Comment: what do you mean by "not running" ? Do you get error or page is displayed but without divs? Give us more details

Comment: My problem is how to make this two lines conditional. I also try this function:  <?php if( is_page_template('agent-list.php'){ ?> ... <?php } ?>

Comment: I get a white page, like nothing appears... Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>

    <!--[if lt IE 7]>      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css"> <![endif]-->

</html>
```